# Serialization of PointCollection using XAML syntax

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

Is it possible to read a C# PointCollection via XML serialization using the more concise XAML-style syntax of

```
<Points>1,2 3,4</Points>
```

Instead of

```
<Points>
    <Point>
        <X>1</X>
        <Y>2</Y>
    </Point>
    <Point>
        <X>3</X>
        <Y>4</Y>
    </Point>
</Points>
```

While I've got the later working fine using the code below, but I'd prefer to use the former if possible.

```
    [XmlElement("Points")]
    public PointCollection Points { get; set; }
```

Comment: Usually I use Select(x,index) => and then use the index value to parse data.

Comment: Specify the exact type of your classes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this using the [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
[XmlIgnore]
public PointCollection Points { get; set; }

[XmlElement("Points")]
public string FakePoints
{
    get { return string.Join(" ", Points.Select(p => p.X + "," + p.Y)); }
    set
    {
        var collection = new PointCollection();
        foreach (var s in value.Split())
        {
            var p = s.Split(',');
            collection.Add(new Point { X = int.Parse(p[0]), Y = int.Parse(p[1]) });
        }
        Points = collection;
    }
}
```

I don't know the exact types of your `PointCollection` and `Point` classes. Perhaps the code can be slightly simplified.

---

If you use [System.Windows.Media.PointCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pointcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [System.Windows.Point](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.point(v=vs.110).aspx) then you can get the desired result using the [System.Xaml.XamlServices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xaml.xamlservices(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Xaml;


public class Foo
{
    public PointCollection Points { get; set; }
}


var foo = new Foo
{
    Points = new PointCollection()
    {
        new Point { X = 1, Y = 2 },
        new Point { X = 3, Y = 4 }
    }
};

using (var fs = new FileStream("test.xml", FileMode.Create))
    XamlServices.Save(fs, foo);

using (var fs = new FileStream("test.xml", FileMode.Open))
    foo = (Foo)XamlServices.Load(fs);
```

Result:

```
<Foo Points="1,2 3,4" xmlns="clr-namespace:;assembly=ConApp" />
```

Comment: This was my fallback approach.  I was just hoping that there was a native way to do it without writing code.  XAML reads the compact format into the same structure, so it seems there must be a way to do it.